# How to test the 5 terminal regulator with multimeter?

Tags: voltage-regulator, multimeter, linear-regulator

How do I test the 5 terminal regulator (e.g. [LM2575](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm2575-d.pdf)) if it's defective or not with the help of multimeter?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are only 4 components to add plus a power supply to get a working circuit: -

[image]

So, I would build one and, you can probably get-away with building it on breadboard. If it produces the correct output voltage (here's where your multimeter comes in) then it's likely not to be defective. You could also load it with 100 Ω and see that the output voltage doesn't change very much too.

Comment: I build same schematic on breadboard, and  supplied 12 volt but receiving 0 volt output. I don't understand., why am I getting  zero output. I have implemented this circuit from two days but same zero volt result.

Comment: Double check what you did. Make sure pin 5 is connected to 0 volts and make sure the diode is the correct way fitted. Make sure you also understand the pin numbering of the LM2575 (double check). Try a new part. Did you buy from a reputable dealer? Has it been subject to damage by being left lying around? Does it physically look damaged. There are fake parts around unfortunately @celin